# Java Generics: how to remove reduntant parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Help me please handle this situation.

I have an abstract class **BasicCommand**:

```
public abstract class BasicCommand<RequestT, ResponseT> {
    protected Collection<ResponseT> execute(RequestT request) {
        return Something;
    }
}
```

I have a class **RequestContext** that contains two objects:

```
public class RequestContext<RequestT> {

    private RequestT requestT;
    private HttpRequest httpRequest;
}
```

Now, I wanna extend my **BasicCommand** which request is parameterized **RequestContext** and response is parameterized ResponseT:

```
public abstract class Command<RequestContext<RequestT>, ResponseT> extends BasicCommand {
    @Override
    public Collection<ResponseT> execute(RequestContext<RequestT> request) {
        return something();
    }
}
```

I know this code won't compile.

After several tries, eventually I came up with this:

```
public abstract class Command<T extends RequestContext<RequestT>, RequestT, ResponseT>
        extends BasicCommand<RequestContext<RequestT>, ResponseT> {
}
```

As you can see the parameter *RequestT* is duplicated.

Just look at this specific implementation of *Command*:

```
public class SpecificCommand extends Command<RequestContext<String>, String, String> {
}
```

A reduntant paremeter is really irritating.
How to change signature of *Command* to make it right ?
The *BasicCommand* is given (I can't change it).
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the parameter `T`. You are not using it.

Try:

```
public abstract class Command<RequestT, ResponseT> extends BasicCommand<RequestContext<RequestT>, ResponseT> {
    @Override
    public Collection<ResponseT> execute(RequestContext<RequestT> request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class SpecificCommand extends Command<String, String> {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer is a lifesaver!